# Error on Workflow: The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more columns for the item require a different type of information

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I noticed that I started experiencing the error when I changed the name field from optional to required. Also, there are instances that the workflow works upon creation but errors out after 2nd or 3rd edit of the item.

I already tried the following:

1. Disabled content approval
2. Added 1 minute pause

This is the workflow:
The following actions will run in parallel:

```
If Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
and Current Item:1st Issue Status equals Open
and Current Item:1st Issue Assigned Team equals Tax
    Email Current Item:Mailbox MIT; Current Item:1st Issue Assigned Analyst

Else if Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
and Current Item:1st Issue Status equals Open
and Current Item:1st Issue Assigned Team equals OTD
    Email Current Item:Mailbox OTD; Current Item:1st Issue Assigned Analyst

Else if Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
and Current Item:1st Issue Status equals Open
and Current Item:1st Issue Assigned Team equals IG CPT
    Email Current Item:Mailbox IG CPT; Current Item:1st Issue Assigned Analyst

Else if Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
and Current Item:1st Issue Status equals Open
and Current Item:1st Issue Assigned Team equals Third Party CPT
    Email Current Item:Mailbox 3rd Party CPT; Current Item:1st Issue Assigned Analyst

Else if Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
and Current Item:1st Issue Status equals Open
and Current Item:1st Issue Assigned Team equals IG Settlements Crude
    Email Current Item:Mailbox IG Settlement Crude; Current Item:1st Issue Assigned Analyst

Else if Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
and Current Item:1st Issue Status equals Open
and Current Item:1st Issue Assigned Team equals IG Settlements Products
    Email Current Item:Mailbox IG Settlement Products; Current Item:1st Issue Assigned Analyst

Else If Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
and Current Item:1st Issue Status equals Open
and Current Item:1st Issue Assigned Team equals TSS
    Email Current Item:Mailbox TSS; Current Item:1st Issue Assigned Analyst

If Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
and Current Item:2nd Issue Status equals Open
and Current Item:2nd Issue Assigned Team equals Tax
    Email Current Item:Mailbox MIT; Current Item:2nd Issue Assigned Analyst

Else if Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
and Current Item:2nd Issue Status equals Open
and Current Item:2nd Issue Assigned Team equals OTD
    Email Current Item:Mailbox OTD; Current Item:2nd Issue Assigned Analyst

Else if Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
and Current Item:2nd Issue Status equals Open
and Current Item:2nd Issue Assigned Team equals IG CPT
    Email Current Item:Mailbox IG CPT; Current Item:2nd Issue Assigned Analyst

Else if Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
and Current Item:2nd Issue Status equals Open
and Current Item:2nd Issue Assigned Team equals Third Party CPT
    Email Current Item:Mailbox 3rd Party CPT; Current Item:2nd Issue Assigned Analyst

Else if Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
and Current Item:2nd Issue Status equals Open
and Current Item:2nd Issue Assigned Team equals IG Settlements Crude
    Email Current Item:Mailbox IG Settlement Crude; Current Item:2nd Issue Assigned Analyst

Else if Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
and Current Item:2nd Issue Status equals Open
and Current Item:2nd Issue Assigned Team equals IG Settlements Products
    Email Current Item:Mailbox IG Settlement Products; Current Item:2nd Issue Assigned Analyst

Else If Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
and Current Item:2nd Issue Status equals Open
and Current Item:2nd Issue Assigned Team equals TSS
    Email Current Item:Mailbox TSS; Current Item:2nd Issue Assigned Analyst

If Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
and Current Item:3rd Issue Status equals Open
and Current Item:3rd Issue Assigned Team equals Tax
    Email Current Item:Mailbox MIT; Current Item:3rd Issue Assigned Analyst

Else if Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
and Current Item:3rd Issue Status equals Open
and Current Item:3rd Issue Assigned Team equals OTD
    Email Current Item:Mailbox OTD; Current Item:3rd Issue Assigned Analyst

Else if Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
and Current Item:3rd Issue Status equals Open
and Current Item:3rd Issue Assigned Team equals IG CPT
    Email Current Item:Mailbox IG CPT; Current Item:3rd Issue Assigned Analyst

Else if Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
and Current Item:3rd Issue Status equals Open
and Current Item:3rd Issue Assigned Team equals Third Party CPT
    Email Current Item:Mailbox 3rd Party CPT; Current Item:3rd Issue Assigned Analyst

Else If Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
and Current Item:3rd Issue Status equals Open
and Current Item:3rd Issue Assigned Team equals IG Settlements Crude
    Email Current Item:Mailbox IG Settlement Crude; Current Item:3rd Issue Assigned Analyst

    If Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
    and Current Item:3rd Issue Status equals Open
    and Current Item:3rd Issue Assigned Team equals IG Settlements Products
        Email Current Item:Mailbox IG Settlement Products; Current Item:3rd Issue Assigned Analyst

    Else If Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
    and Current Item:3rd Issue Status equals Open
    and Current Item:3rd Issue Assigned Team equals TSS
        Email Current Item:Mailbox TSS; Current Item:3rd Issue Assigned Analyst

    If Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
    and Current Item:4th Issue Status equals Open
    and Current Item:4th Issue Assigned Team equals Tax
        Email Current Item:Mailbox MIT; Current Item:4th Issue Assigned Analyst

    Else if Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
    and Current Item:4th Issue Status equals Open
    and Current Item:4th Issue Assigned Team equals OTD
        Email Current Item:Mailbox OTD; Current Item:4th Issue Assigned Analyst

    Else if Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
    and Current Item:4th Issue Status equals Open
    and Current Item:4th Issue Assigned Team equals IG CPT
        Email Current Item:Mailbox IG CPT; Current Item:4th Issue Assigned Analyst

    Else if Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
    and Current Item:4th Issue Status equals Open
    and Current Item:4th Issue Assigned Team equals Third Party CPT
        Email Current Item:Mailbox 3rd Party CPT; Current Item:4th Issue Assigned Analyst
    Else if Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
    and Current Item:4th Issue Status equals Open
    and Current Item:4th Issue Assigned Team equals IG Settlements Crude
        Email Current Item:Mailbox IG Settlement Crude; Current Item:4th Issue Assigned Analyst
    Else if Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
    and Current Item:4th Issue Status equals Open
    and Current Item:4th Issue Assigned Team equals IG Settlements Products
        Email Current Item:Mailbox IG Settlement Products; Current Item:4th Issue Assigned Analyst
    Else
    If Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
    and Current Item:4th Issue Status equals Open
    and Current Item:4th Issue Assigned Team equals TSS
        Email Current Item:Mailbox TSS; Current Item:4th Issue Assigned Analyst
    If Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
    and Current Item:5th Issue Status equals Open
    and Current Item:5th Issue Assigned Team equals Tax
        Email Current Item:Mailbox MIT; Current Item:5th Issue Assigned Analyst
    Else if Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
    and Current Item:5th Issue Status equals Open
    and Current Item:5th Issue Assigned Team equals OTD
        Email Current Item:Mailbox OTD; Current Item:5th Issue Assigned Analyst
    Else if Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
    and Current Item:5th Issue Status equals Open
    and Current Item:5th Issue Assigned Team equals IG CPT
        Email Current Item:Mailbox IG CPT; Current Item:5th Issue Assigned Analyst
    Else if Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
    and Current Item:5th Issue Status equals Open
    and Current Item:5th Issue Assigned Team equals Third Party CPT
        Email Current Item:Mailbox 3rd Party CPT; Current Item:5th Issue Assigned Analyst
    Else if Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
    and Current Item:5th Issue Status equals Open
    and Current Item:5th Issue Assigned Team equals IG Settlements Crude
        Email Current Item:Mailbox IG Settlement Crude; Current Item:5th Issue Assigned Analyst
    Else if Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
    and Current Item:5th Issue Status equals Open
    and Current Item:5th Issue Assigned Team equals IG Settlements Products
        Email Current Item:Mailbox IG Settlement Products; Current Item:5th Issue Assigned Analyst
    Else
    If Current Item:Workflow Intitiated equals No
    and Current Item:5th Issue Status equals Open
    and Current Item:5th Issue Assigned Team equals TSS
        Email Current Item:Mailbox TSS; Current Item:5th Issue Assigned Analyst
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there an InfoPath form associated with this list? If that is the case I would open it and re-publish the form. This should clear the issue.